# Как узнать классы или библиотеки python которые установлены в данный момент?

Tags: python

Есть ли возможность при помощи какой-нить команды узнать те классы или библиотеки python которые установлены в данный момент? а так же встроенные в них? (например: tkinter, Qt, PyQt5, QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QFrame, QLabel, QMenu)

(типа как help в командной строке или что-то подобное)

Comment: Можно импорт модуля обернуть в try-except, и отлавливать исключение ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: Пример есть? или ссылка где почитать? Как сделать чтобы при ошибке окно python не закрывалось?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/h9B37f9q

Comment: меня интересует что-то типа "pip list", только вот в этом списке я не вижу tkinter...

Comment: tkinter не ставится через pip: он или ставится при установке самого python под windows, или через системный менеджер пакетов (например `sudo apt install python3-tk`). Поэтому его не будет в списке выдваемом через pip list.

Answer (score 2):

py -m pydoc modules (в коммандную строку)

Answer (score 1):

Для просмотра установленных бибилиотек необоходимо вызвать:

pip freeze